# MatMenuItemHarness not picking up items

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine

I am trying to access ad click a `mat-menu-item` button. I am using the `MatMenuItemHarness` to access the element but the test is failing with the message:

> Error: Failed to find element matching one of the following queries:
> (MatMenuItemHarness with host element matching selector: ".mat-mdc-menu-item")

Here's the relevant html:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="user-menu">
  <button
    mat-menu-item
    class="edit-profile-button"
    aria-label="Edit profile button"
    [routerLink]="['../edit-profile']"
    >Edit Profile
  </button>
  <button
    mat-menu-item
    aria-label="Logout button"
    class="logout-button"
    (click)="logout()"
    >Logout
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Here's the test:

```
  describe('logout button', () => {
    it('should emit the logoutUser event when clicked', async () => {
      spyOn(component.logoutUser, 'emit');
      component.loggedOnUser$ = of(new User());
      const userMenu = await loader.getHarness(MatMenuHarness);
      await userMenu.open();
      const btn = await loader.getHarness(MatMenuItemHarness);
      await btn.click();
      expect(component.logoutUser.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

I have setup another test which confirms the menu items are present when the test is run:

```
  describe('logout button', () => {
    it('should emit the logoutUser event when clicked', async () => {
      component.loggedOnUser$ = of(new User());
      const userMenu = await loader.getHarness(MatMenuHarness);
      await userMenu.open();
      const items = await userMenu.getItems();
      expect(items.length).toBe(2) // THIS PASSES
      expect((await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatMenuItemHarness)).length).toBe(2); //THIS FAILS
    });
  });
```

Here is the test module setup:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ToolbarComponent,
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ]
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ToolbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  });
```

Does anybody know why the `MatMenuItemHarness` is not working in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same question. So I dive into [the code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/menu/testing/menu-harness.ts#L149) and it's dawn on me that menu item basically exists is a panel.
That's the reason why you can't get the harnesses by calling loader.getAllHarnesses(MatMenuItemHarness).